# Finite sum of product of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Finite_products_of_trigonometric_functions), under the section Finite products of trigonometric functions, there is this identity that says for coprime integers $n,m$ the following result holds

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(2a+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi km}{n}+x\right)\right)=2T_{n}\left(a\right)+\left(-1\right)^{n+m}\cos\left(nx\right)$$

where $T_n$ is the Chebyshev polynomial.

My question was originally about the product

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\right)$$ where $n$ is a prime number greater than 3. I noticed that I can use the identity and set $a=\frac{1}{2}, x=0$ and $m=1$ to get the answer 3 to the product. However, I really do not understand how the identity is derived. Does someone has a reference or a link to how the result is obtained? Thanks in advance.

Comment: see https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1111810p5071274 taking into account the fact that $T_n(a)=\cos(n \alpha)$ if you set $a:=\cos \alpha$.